# How to use a scikit learn model from C#

Tags: c#, scikit-learn

I made many models with scikit learn, and i want to make predictions with these models from a C# program, is there any API which will help me to do that ?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to load sklearn models in C# directly (for my knowledge).

There is a language for the language-/tool-independent exchange of ML models called PMML. sklearn doesn't bring native support for PMML however. If you're lucky, your model/pipeline might be exportable to PMML using [third party tools](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn) and loadable in C# using [third party libraries](https://help.syncfusion.com/predictive-analytics/pmml-execution-engine/overview).

The more reliable and way more flexible way is to do the prediction in Python using sklearn and communicate with your C# program via files or (better) a web service. Olivier Grisel (one of the sklearn authors) concisely describes your options in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12743013).