# How to embed sklearn models to mobile for offline use?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, scikit-learn

I need to embed scikit-learn models in an iOS and Androis apps, in particular svm and random forest.

I have deployed keras models using a converted version with tflite but could not find a way to use sklearn ones.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the platform, there are wrapper libraries that allow for the use of Scikit-learn on mobile.

For iOS, you should be able to do this with CoreML/CoreMLTools by looking at [coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert.html). It does provide 'random forest', not svm currently, but based on the libraries code (i.e. coremltool + scikitlearn), you should be able to expand it to work with svm as well.

For Android, you might be able to find information on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738827/how-can-i-call-scikit-learn-classifiers-from-java).